# Can terminal be launched via keyboard shortcut: CTRL+ALT+T?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

I am using Alfred and hence I don't have any use for the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut. I want to invoke terminal using that shortcut. Just like in Ubuntu, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

I don't want to use Alfred to start the terminal. I just want to press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and I want the terminal to appear just like it would in Ubuntu.

Is there a way to start terminal like that in OS X Mavericks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### [**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)

You can do this with Keyboard Maestro, using a macro such as this:

[image]

### Alfred

You can set up a custom hotkey to launch an app using a workflow:

[image]

Go to the workflows tab, create a new workflow and add a hotkey and a 'launch apps' with Terminal selected as the app to launch.

### [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/)

You can use KeyRemap4MacBook with a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_Terminal</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>Activate Terminal with ⌘Space</name>
    <identifier>ActivateTerminalWithCmdSpace</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::SPACE, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_Terminal
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

### Automator Service

You can create a service in Automator:

[image: Open Terminal]

…then in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Services you can assign a keyboard command to run it.

Comment: Can't it be done natively like in Windows and Linux? I am asking because KeyBoard Maestro and alfred are not free.

Comment: @Morpheus Added a method using KeyRemap4MacBook which is free

Comment: should keyremapformacbook be open all the time for this to run?

Comment: @Morpheus The app doesn't need to be open — it adds a daemon.

Comment: @Morpheus Added Automator method

Comment: @grgaside, automator is not working but keyremap is working. SO thanks!

Comment: Automator method works for me on Catalina. Didn't work at first, but then I realized that I hadn't chosen a unique keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to achieve the same behavior as Ubuntu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by combining following two steps:

1. Set up an Automator service to open `iTerm2`: Open Automator app, select "Quick Action" from the menu[image: Quick Action] and assign it a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. 
   [image]This will open the app but won't open any more windows (so if the app is open the keyboard shortcut doesn't have an effect).
2. Add an iTerm2 key mapping to open subsequent windows. In iTerm2 preferences:
   [image]

**There you have it, no external app needed but far from straight forward**

Comment: Thanks. Note that some keyboard shortcuts dont work randomly. For instance, just F4 didnt work to open an app I wanted. However, Command+F4 worked.

Comment: Great one! Just a few hints: Remember to store the shortcut in Automator with `Cmd` + `S`. Todoist users have to change the command because `Ctrl` + `Cmd` + `T` is already used there.

Comment: On sonoma I could manage to make this work, but they have moved a little bit the settings (both on mac and iterm2 settings). But thanks for the ideas!!!!!

Answer (score 10):

5 months late, but I think this bit is useful.

As far as an automator solution goes this is probably a little better. Instead of running finder just use an applescript. ie add action "Utilities Run AppleScript". Run this script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"
        do script " "
        activate
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

This will not only open terminal, when run multiple times it will open multiple windows. Then just add a hotkey for it in services (under keyboard), as explained in George Garside's answer.

Comment: error when saving: `Expected end of line but found "script"`

Comment: You can find useful [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35954589/3848267) stackoverflow answer, it is the same approach than [@tlane answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140215) but very detailed in it's implementation, very useful for someone totally new to MacOS.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this very easily with [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net):

[image: btt-snapshot]

As the "Specific Application" to open the selected/active folder with, I chose Terminal.

Thus when I use the keyboard shortcut specified (I use option-'), the *current Folder* is opened in the Terminal.

Answer (score 4):

In iTerm2, you can go to iterm preferences, keys -> hotkeys ->  set in your key command.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use iTerm (iTerm2), do the same as [@tlane's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140215/145449), except use this for the AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if application "iTerm" is running then
        tell application "iTerm"
            create window with default profile
            activate
        end tell
    else
        tell application "iTerm"
            activate
        end tell
    end if

    return input
end run
```

Comment: I added this in automator, and within automator, it works great. However, when I assign a keyboard shortcut for this service, it does nothing. Is there anything else I need to watch out for?

Comment: @s-heins perhaps the keyboard shortcut you tried is already used by other software such as the OS?  I used control+option+command+T, and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I've come with macOS ***as-is*** and no mods or 3rd party software:

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
   Opens the ***U***tilities sub-folder in /Applications/ (where Terminal.app lives)
2. <kbd>t</kbd>
   Selects the ***T***erminal.app
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>
   ***O***pens the Terminal.app and closes the finder window.

This has worked since day one with every OSX release.

With a slight modification to `System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts::Services`, this is a close runner up, but it requires that you select a folder first:
[image]

...for example from the Finder at login you could

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and your home directory `~/` would open in the Finder, then
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> again to the /Users/ directory. Now your user home directory `~/` should be selected (if in list or icon view, not column).
3. If you then hit your custom "Services" key combination (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) to launch a "New Terminal at Folder" the Terminal.app will launch at your home directory `~/`

Lastly, in an effort to get something as close as possible to launching a Terminal.app window from the Finder with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>... Since the <kbd>Option</kbd> key is kinda equivalent to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key... using the "Services" custom key combo to launch a "New Terminal at Folder" you could also create an alias of your home directory on the desktop. If you rename the alias <kbd>Space</kbd>, then from the Finder it's:

1. <kbd>Space</kbd> to select your `~/` alias, then
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to Open a Terminal there.

...and you end up with a little home living on your desktop which has an arrow pointing to it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use [Quicksilver](https://qsapp.com)

1. Make a new Trigger in Quicksilver by opening Triggers (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> when Quicksiver is opened)
2. Click the `+▾` button at te botten of the list and select `Keyboard`

[image: Add new keyboard shortcut to a app]

3. Type `terminal` and this wil show terminal.app then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the `Save` button
4. Assign a keyboard shortcut to that trigger by clicking on `Keyboard` and a slide out window wil, er, slide out
5. Then, lastly, click on the empty box after `Shortcut:` and press your favourite key combination

[image: Quicksilver Triggers overview]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without using any 3rd party applications:

- Open Keyboard settings and navigate to Shortcuts tab
- Now, goto App Shortcuts
- Click on + symbol, choose your Terminal app (If you haven't found the Terminal app, choose "other" and will navigate to the Finder, then search for Terminal)
- naming the shortcut and the shortcut keys that would like to give.

Comment: I wish that would work, but they say: "You can’t create keyboard shortcuts for general purpose tasks, such as opening an app" (https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/10.14/mac/10.14), however there seems to be a solution with automator (not tested yet): https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/03/14/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-launch-apps-in-macos-using-automator

Comment: Has anyone had success with this process?  This did not work on Catalina

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly on Big Sure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer because if you're a linux person trying to get out of this hell, the solution I found is:

1. Using BetterTouchTool2 to map <kbd>Ctrl-Cmd-T</kbd> to run <kbd>Cmd-N</kbd> in specific application but..
2. Use Alacritty as terminal.  This very light terminal window does NOT assume the apple parent / child hierarchy.

The one gotcha is that Alacritty has to actually be running already, so I added it to my login apps.  I use LOTS of terminals so I don't care about this limitation. The chances of me not having a terminal window open on some desktop is close to none.  As a bonus, I can now open multiple terminals with my preferred keyboard shortcut AND "alt-tab".. or Apple Tab between them.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool no one has mentioned is [skhd](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd). Adding the following to `$HOME/.skhdrc` will do this trick:

```
ctrl + alt - t : osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm2" to create window with default profile command ""' || open -na iTerm
```