# Shortcut for opening an app?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, shortcut

I am using a Macbook Pro (Retina, Mid-2014) running El Capitan. Is there a way to set a shortcut that opens a specific app (in my case Activity Monitor)?

Comment: What about Spotlight (⌘+Space bar) and entering first letters of an app?

Comment: You mean a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find [several](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120298/open-terminal-using-a-keyboard-shortcut) solutions (Keyboard Maestro, Karabiner, Automator Wrapper) or [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=launchbar%20quicksilver) (LaunchBar/Quicksilver) to accomplish this.

Another [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) solution is the **Launcher Mode**:

[image]

1. Download, install and start Karabiner.
2. In the menubar open Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Search for *Launcher* and enable the preset.
4. To open Activity Monitor hold <kbd>O</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and release <kbd>A</kbd>