# Alt+Enter Shortcut in MacOS

Tags: terminal, keyboard, software-recommendation, shortcut, settings

For over 10 years I have been using Linux, where I always had Alt+Enter as a shortcut to open a new terminal. Recently due to employment change I have to use MacOS. About 100 times a day I hit Alt+Enter with nothing happening. I would like to set or hack my beloved shortcut into MacOS. Using Shortcuts in System Preferences/Keyboard does not seem to accept the Enter key.

You would earn my eternal gratitude by pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You can use Opt/Enter (or Return) as a shortcut. What are you using as your Menu trigger?

Comment: You need to use fn + Return in order to put Return key into keyboard shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg - since when? Is that a laptop thing? I only have Mac Pros here, no laptops to test.

Comment: @Tetsujin - since never. My mistake, one can put Return without Fn into shortcut.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Creating System-Wide Keyboard Shortcut To Launch Applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167974/136834)

Comment: Can not get it working. When I press Alt+Enter it just inputs nothing and the shortcut remains empty 'Add Shortcut'. I've tried with Control as well. I've tried using the Fn key together with Enter. It appears to be working with 'App Shortcut' but what I need is a 'Services' shortcut. I have switched Control and Command on my system. I have tried using both the Mac as well as an external keyboard. Both using big return as well as numpad return. Please assist. I'm open to hacking it in through the commandline. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm… true. Doesn't work for Services. I can see you're going to need something like [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)

Answer (score -2):

You can try and follow the Automator action at the following related post.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120300/316076

I do something like this to launch my work apps in the morning.